# Step out of a query to get where clauses from a separate table, within a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a procedure which I'm using to output row counts to a .csv file but some of the where clauses I may want to use are contained in a table. How can I use them to create conditions for the counts?

I've attempted using concatenation pipes to select against the table that holds the where clauses but I'm confused about syntax and where they should go and I believe this is where I need the most help.

These are the columns in the table that contains some of the where clauses I ultimately want to use in the procedure.

```
SCHEMA,  DATABASE,  FULL_TABLE,  DRIVER_TABLE,  MAND_JOIN
```

And the values may be such as:

```
PROD,  DB1,  RLTSHP,  BOB.R_ID,  A.AR_ID = B.AR_ID
```

The procedure I have written is as follows:

```
create or replace procedure PROJECT is
  --variables
  l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'DB1';
  ROW_COUNT number;
  file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
BEGIN
  utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'OWNER,TABLE_NAME,ROW_COUNT');

  --main loop
  for rws in (select /*+parallel */ owner, table_name
                from dba_tables@DB1 a
               where table_name in (select table_name
                                      from meta_table
                                     where driver_table is not null
                                       and additional_joins is null)
                 and a.owner in (select distinct schema
                                   from meta_table c)
               order by table_name)
  loop
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' ||rws.owner||'.'||rws.table_name || '@' || l_dblink into ROW_COUNT;
    utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                      rws.OWNER || ',' ||
                      rws.TABLE_NAME || ',' ||
                      ROW_COUNT);
  end loop;
END PROJECT;
/
```

However, instead of the simple `select count(*)` reflected in the above, I want to find a way to include data in the meta_table to construct "where" clauses that use table joins to limit the output so that I'm not counting all rows, but rows that meet the criteria in the join I've constructed.

For example, so that the actual count that gets executed will be something like this:

```
select count(*)
  from PROD.RLTSHP@DB1 b,
       BOB.R_ID@DB1 a
 where A.AR_ID = B.AR_ID;
```

Essentially I would be constructing the query using the entries in the meta_table. I think I can do this with concat's / pipes but I'm not sure exactly how to.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend your simple statement to assemble the join criteria as well. The one catch is that you must give the tables aliases which match the aliases used in `additional_joins` i.e. `B` for FULL and `A` for DRIVER. These have to be standard for all rows in your META_TABLE otherwise you will generate invalid SQL.

```
create or replace procedure PROJECT is
  l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'DB1';
  ROW_COUNT number;
  file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
  v_sql varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'OWNER,TABLE_NAME,ROW_COUNT');

  << main_loop >>
  for rws in (select mt.*
              from dba_tables@DB1 db
                join meta_table mt
                  on mt.driver_table = db.table_name
                  and mt.owner = db.owner
               where mt.db_link = l_dblink 
               order by mt.table_name)
  loop    
    -- simple query
    v_sql := 'select count(*) from ' || rws.owner||'.'||rws.driver_table || '@' || l_dblink;

    -- join query
    if rws.additional_joins is not null 
       and rws.full_table is not null then 
       v_sql := v_sql|| ' b, '|| rws.full_table ||'@'||l_dblink|| ' a where ' ||rws.additional_joins;
    end if;

    -- uncomment this for debugging
    --dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);

    execute immediate v_sql into ROW_COUNT;
    utl_file.put(file_handle,
                      rws.OWNER || ',' ||
                      rws.TABLE_NAME || ',' ||
     utl_file.put_line(file_handle, ROW_COUNT);

  end loop main_loop;

END PROJECT;
/
```

**Notes**

We have to use a variable to assemble the statement because the final SQL is conditional on the contents of a row. This enables efficient debugging because we have something we can display. Dynamic SQL is hard, because it turns compilation errors into runtime errors. Diagnosis is difficult when we can't see the actual executed code.

I have tweaked your driving query to make the joins safer.

The column names you used in the code are not consist with the column names you used for the table structure. So there may be naming bugs which you'll need to fix for yourself.

I have retained the Old Skool implicit join syntax. I was tempted to generate ANSI 92 SQL (`inner join ... on`) but it's not clear that the `additional_joins` will contain only join criteria.

Pro tip. Instead of commenting your loops - `--main loop` - use an actual PL/SQL label - `<<main_loop>>` so you can link the matching `end loop` statement, as I have done in this code.

Improvements you may want to add:

- validate that FULL_TABLE exists in target database
- include FULL_TABLE in UTL_FILE output
- validate that columns referenced in ADDITIONAL_JOIN are valid (using DBA_TAB_COLUMNS, but it's trickier because you will have to parse the column names from the text)
- worry about whether the content of ADDITIONAL_JOIN is a valid *and complete* join condition

Comment: Thank you! One thing, I am getting: 

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "B"."END_DTE": invalid identifier

When referencing one of the join conditions. 

I have referenced these in the following way:

execute immediate' select /*+parallel */ count(*) from ' ||rws.owner||'.'||rws.table_name || '@' || l_dblink||' a '||','||
rws.driver_table || '@' || l_dblink||' b ' ||' where ' ||rws.mandatory_join ||' and '||rws.additional_joins

Additional joins contains special characters, as follows:

B.END_DTE >= '01-OCT-2018'

Do you know if I need to escape these in some way?

Comment: Well that seems like the table in DRIVER_TABLE doesn't have a column called END_DTE. You'll need to verify it against DBA_TAB_COLUMNS. Also it's a problem because it's a filter not a join condition, so the generated query would be a product of tables A and B.

Comment: I've debugged the code using dbms_output, and what it is writing in the loop
is as follows:

select /*+parallel */ count(*) from SCHEMA1.TABLE1@DB1 a
,SCHEMA2.TABLE2@DB1 b  where A.AR_ID = B.AR_ID and B.END_DTE >=
'01-DEC-2018'

Which results in:

ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "B"."END_DTE": invalid identifier

Comment: So, I did have one bad entry in the driver table, now though, it definitely seems to be the B.END_DTE >= '01-DEC-2018' part... it must need some quotes or something?

Comment: Actually - no I've sussed it, with your help. The column didn't exist in that table... that was all! So happy - it's sorted now. Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't recommend to use PARALLEL hint. It can kill your db if you will have a lot of queries with PARALLEL hints.

I assume that columns MAND_JOIN means, that always we have value there.

```
create or replace procedure PROJECT is

  lc_sql_template CONSTANT varchar2(4000) := 
              'select count(*) '                                    || CHR(10) ||
              '  from #TableOwner.#TableName@DB1 b'                 || CHR(10) ||
              ' inner join #FullTableName@DB1    a ON #JoinCodition';

  lv_row_count   number;
  lv_file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
  lv_sql         varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  utl_file.put_line(lv_file_handle, 'OWNER,TABLE_NAME,ROW_COUNT');

  for rws in (select mt.*
                from dba_tables@DB1  db
               inner join meta_table mt
                       on mt.driver_table = db.table_name
                      and mt.owner        = db.owner
               where mt.driver_table     is not null
                 and mt.additional_joins is null  
               order by mt.table_name)
  loop

    lv_sql := lc_sql_template;
    lv_sql := replace(lv_sql, '#TableOwner'    , rws.owner);
    lv_sql := replace(lv_sql, '#TableName'     , rws.driver_table);
    lv_sql := replace(lv_sql, '#FullTableName' , rws.full_table);
    lv_sql := replace(lv_sql, '#JoinCodition'  , rws.mand_join);

    $if $$DevMode = true $then -- I even recommand to log this all the time
      your_log_package.info(lv_sql);
    $end

    execute immediate lv_sql into lv_row_count;
    utl_file.put(lv_file_handle, rws.OWNER || ',' || rws.TABLE_NAME || ',' || lv_row_count);

  end loop main_loop;

exception
  when others then
      your_log_package.error(lv_sql);
     raise;
end PROJECT;
```